# Что означает выражение type & l_t?

Tags: c++

```
struct Example
{
    Example(int l_t):
    type(l_t)
    {

    }

    void set(int &l_t)
    {
        type= type & l_t;
    }

    int type;
};
```

Что выполняется в функции set? Аргументу из функции присваивается тип type или что?

Comment: А учебники читать, не?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сигнатуре функции `set` символ `&` используется как часть типа и обозначает ссылку. В теле функции символ `&` используется для осуществления побитовой операции И, эквивалентно `bitand`.

Answer (score 1):

`type` - член структуры `Example`. & - это оператор побитовое И. В член-функции `set` в выражении `type = type & l_t;` члену `type` присваивается результат вычисления `type & l_t`.

Например, если `l_t = 0b101, type = 0b011` (приставка 0b означает представление в двоичном виде), то результат выражения будет `0b001`